# Finding the voltage at which saturation current is achieved

Tags: photoelectric-effect, photon-emission

In the photoelectric effect, while studying saturation current, I saw that in most graphs with voltage, this saturation current is achieved relatively early at a certain "threshold" voltage of sorts, after which it does not increase further. Is there any way to calculate the threshold voltage (our teacher called it the knock-voltage) at which saturation current is first achieved? Or is saturation current always achieved only at an infinitely high voltage? If there's no way to calculate this voltage, can I get a qualitative idea of what this voltage would depend on?